# Undo button when suggesting tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

I was just proposing a tag synonym and I accidentally proposed it to the wrong tag.  I was aiming to associate "associative-array" and another spelling of the same thing, and I ended up doing the association with associative-array and the c++ tag.

This is an obvious error.  Unfortunately I can't seem to "undo", unpropose, or whatever to get rid of it so it will end up wasting someone else's time.

I think it would be good to be able to kill/delete your own tag synonym proposition as a feature - or if that feature is available somehow, I'd propose making it more obvious because I couldn't find it.

Comment: Or at least delete your own tag synonym suggestion in a following amount of time after proposing as long as no one had already voted.